# How do I create multiple dictionaries based on nested for loops?

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration

Here is the output I am wanting:

```
level1 = {'value1':0, 'value2':0, 'value3':0}
level2 = {'value1':0, 'value2':0, 'value3':0}
level3 = {'value1':0, 'value2':0, 'value3':0}
level3 = {'value1':0, 'value2':0, 'value3':0}
```

Note: Value1, Value2, and Value3 are all the same thing. I am using this to just populate the dictionaries.

Here is what I am trying:

```
for x in range (1,6):
    level = 'level%d' % x
    for iteration in range(1, 4):
        value = 'value%d' % iteration
    level = {}
        level['value'] = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying something like this?:

```
dic={}
for x in range (1,6):
    level = 'level%d' % x 
    dic[level] = {}
    for iteration in range(1, 4): 
        value = 'value%d' % iteration
        dic[level][value] = 0 

print dic
```

Output:

```
{'level1': {'value1': 0, 'value2': 0, 'value3': 0},
 'level2': {'value1': 0, 'value2': 0, 'value3': 0},
 'level3': {'value1': 0, 'value2': 0, 'value3': 0},
 'level4': {'value1': 0, 'value2': 0, 'value3': 0},
 'level5': {'value1': 0, 'value2': 0, 'value3': 0}}
```

Comment: It could be simplified further with a defaultdict or dict comprehension, depending on the needs. Also, `str.format` is preferred over `%` for new code.

Comment: I am not familiar with nested dictionaries.. How do I access the value1 of the dictionary level3?

Comment: Use `print dic['level3']['value1']`

Answer (score 1):

So you want something like:

```
keys = ('value1','value2','value3')
{k:dict.fromkeys(keys,0) for k in range(1,4)}
```

demo:

```
>>> keys = ('value1','value2','value3')
>>> {k:dict.fromkeys(keys,0) for k in range(1,4)}
{1: {'value3': 0, 'value2': 0, 'value1': 0}, 2: {'value3': 0, 'value2': 0, 'value1': 0}, 3: {'value3': 0, 'value2': 0, 'value1': 0}}
```

Of course, with sequential integers as keys, you might consider indexing from 0 and using a list comprehension instead:

```
[dict.fromkeys(keys,0) for _ in range(3)]
```

Comment: Looks nice but can get messy if there are more then 3 or five levels ;)

Comment: @hevnsnt -- I'm not sure I follow.  What do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

You can nest the`for`loops in a nested [dictionary comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-sets-and-dictionaries) and create a two-level nested dictionary like this:

```
from pprint import pprint

nested_dict = {'level%d' % level:
                    {'value%d' % value: 0 for value in range(1, 4)}
                                                 for level in range(1, 6)}
pprint(nested_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'level1': {'value1': 0, 'value2': 0, 'value3': 0},
 'level2': {'value1': 0, 'value2': 0, 'value3': 0},
 'level3': {'value1': 0, 'value2': 0, 'value3': 0},
 'level4': {'value1': 0, 'value2': 0, 'value3': 0},
 'level5': {'value1': 0, 'value2': 0, 'value3': 0}}
```